# Azure DevOps iOS and Android React Native Build Failing on Pod Install and Gradle Build Steps

Tags: android, ios, gradle, azure-devops, cocoapods

I am trying to create CI/CD pipeline, for iOS and android, in Azure Devops for a React-Native app.

With the android pipeline, whether I choose to create a yaml or use the classic editor and use pre-configured android tasks, the pipeline always fails on the build task (bundleRelease). The error I receive is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Settings file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app-rn/android/settings.gradle' line: 12
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'iEquos'.

> Could not read script '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app-rn/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Error: The process '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app-rn/android/gradlew' failed with exit code 1
at ExecState._setResult (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.200.2/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:944:25)
at ExecState.CheckComplete (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.200.2/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:927:18)
at ChildProcess. (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.200.2/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:840:19)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
##[error]Error: The process '/home/vsts/work/1/s/app-rn/android/gradlew' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Gradle

This is line being referred to in android/settings.gradle:

apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings, "../")

The node modules folder is in the 'app-rn' directory, at the same level as the "android" folder, so only using one "../" is correct?

I can build the android solution locally through a termianl or using Android studio so I am completely clueless to why this is occurring in DevOps.

A similar issue is occurring with my pipeline for iOS. The issue is occurring when istalling Cocoa Pods:

[DevOps Install Cocoa Pods Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00QOC.png)

Here is an image of my PodFile, located in the 'iOS' folder. The 'iOS' folder is located at the same level as 'node-modules', both inside a folder 'app-rn':

[Podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4cJE.png)

Here is the yaml for android:

```
# Android
# Build your Android project with Gradle.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute the APK, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/android
variables:
  - group: DriverApp

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

name: $(date:yyyy).$(Month)$(rev:.r)

steps:

- script: yarn install

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: 'app-rn/android/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: 'app-rn/android/'
    options: '-PversionName=$(Build.BuildNumber) -PversionCode=$(Build.BuildId)'
    tasks: 'bundleRelease'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false

- task: AndroidSigning@3
  inputs:
    apkFiles: '**/*.aab'
    apksignerKeystoreFile: 'keystore.jks'
    apksignerKeystorePassword: '$(AndroidKeyStorePassword)'
    apksignerKeystoreAlias: '$(AndroidKeyAlias)'
    apksignerKeyPassword: '$(AndroidKeyAliasPassword)'
    zipalign: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    # PathtoPublish: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/release'
    PathtoPublish: 'android/app/build/outputs/'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

The yaml for iOS:

```
# trigger:
#   branches:
#     include:
#       - master
variables:
  - group: DriverApp
pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'
steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
    clean: true
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: 'Install Node'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '12.19.0' # you can use your desired version here
      # workingDirectory: 'app-rn/'
  - script: yarn install
    displayName: Install Dependencies
  - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
    displayName: Install Apple Certificate
    inputs:
      certSecureFile: 'AppleDistributionCertificate.p12'
      certPwd: '$(AppleCertificatePassword)'
      keychain: 'temp'
      deleteCert: true
  - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
    displayName: 'Install Apple Provisioning Profile'
    inputs:
      provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
      provProfileSecureFile: 'iEquos_App_Store.mobileprovision'
      removeProfile: true
  - task: CocoaPods@0
    displayName: 'Install CocoaPods'
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: 'app-rn/ios'
  - task: Xcode@5
    displayName: 'Build IPA'
    inputs:
      actions: 'build'
      configuration: 'Release'
      sdk: 'iphoneos'
      xcWorkspacePath: 'app-rn/ios/iEquos.xcworkspace'
      scheme: 'iEquos'
      packageApp: true
      exportPath: 'output'
      signingOption: 'manual'
      signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
      provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy IPA'
    inputs:
      contents: '**/*.ipa'
      targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
      overWrite: true
      flattenFolders: true
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish IPA to artifacts'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'ios'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

I have searched stackoverflow for similar issues, but only seem to find people running into these issues locally, nto within DevOps. As I mentioned before, I can build the android and iOS app locally.

I am fairly new to posting on stack overflow so please let me know if I should provide anymore information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried add the npm task with npm install command to generate the necessary files, including react.gradle?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Thanks for the reply. I have added a task for npm install, I am still getting the same error for my gradle task

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this in `azure-pipelines.yml` file:

```
- script: /usr/local/bin/pod deintegrate
  workingDirectory: 'app-rn/ios'
  displayName: 'pod deintegrate'

- script: /usr/local/bin/pod install
  workingDirectory: 'app-rn/ios'
  displayName: 'pod install'
```

insted of:

```
- task: CocoaPods@0
  displayName: 'Install CocoaPods'
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: 'app-rn/ios'
```